# Reputation is falsely calculated after voting for a question and an answer which is answered by the same user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I have voted for an answer to the question [find svn revision by removed text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2735890/256544) which was answered by the OP. After voting for the answer I also voted for the question. Then I refreshed the page and I found that the reputation score was wrongly increased. The former score was 194 and after my votings the score was 308. First I was suprised by the big increase, so I visited the [user reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237524/martin-ljchan?tab=reputation) and I found that an "Association Bonus" of 100 was added right along with my votes. I know that this Bonus is awarded if I associate a StackExchange account with another account on the StackExchange network, but it seems to be awarded falsely at this point.

The next thing is the wrong sum: all the reputation points summarize to 307 and not 308. Together with my votes and the Association bonus there should have been added 115 points to 194, but there are 114 points of bonus.

Comment: The user's reputation was 193 before your upvotes, which can be seen in [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u1XYz.png) of Google's [cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/2735890/find-svn-revision-by-removed-text) from last week.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Thank you for the adjustment! Anyhow the 194 must have been branded in my retina. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The association bonus is awarded once the *first* associated account goes over 200.

Your first upvote pushed the account reputation to over 200, hence the association bonus kicked in.

As for the reputation not adding up - you are forgetting the initial 1 rep that everyone starts with :)

Comment: True - also note he got the bonus in the same time on [his other account](http://superuser.com/users/98576/martin-ljchan?tab=reputation)

Comment: But the initial 1 rep should already have been included in the 194 score.

Comment: @splash - True. Didn't consider that bit. It is possible that the person in question undid a downvote, or that an answer that he downvoted on was deleted. A moderator will be able to confirm that, as 10k users can't see that. The reputation does add up correctly for me.